# Unusual Scheme `let` binding, what is `f`?

Tags: syntax, binding, scheme, lisp, let

In *"The Scheme Programming Language 4th Edition"* section 3.3 [Continuations](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/further.html#./further:h3) the following example is given:

```
(define product
  (lambda (ls)
    (call/cc
      (lambda (break)
        (let f ([ls ls])
          (cond
            [(null? ls) 1]
            [(= (car ls) 0) (break 0)]
            [else (* (car ls) (f (cdr ls)))]))))))
```

I can confirm it works in chezscheme as written:

```
> (product '(1 2 3 4 5))
120
```

What is '`f`' in the above `let`? Why is the given `ls` being assigned to itself? It doesn't seem to match what I understand about `(let ...)` as described in 4.4 [local binding](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/binding.html#./binding:h4):

```
syntax: (let ((var expr) ...) body1 body2 ...)
```

If '`f`' is being defined here I would expect it inside parenthesis/square brackets:

```
(let ([f some-value]) ...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 'named let', and it's a syntactic convenience.

```
(let f ([x y] ...)
  ...
  (f ...)
  ...)
```

is more-or-less equivalent to

```
(letrec ([f (λ (x ...)
              ...
              (f ...)
              ...)])
  (f y ...))
```

or, in suitable contexts, to a local `define` followed by a call:

```
(define (outer ...)
  (let inner ([x y] ...)
    ...
    (inner ...)
    ...))
```

is more-or-less equivalent to

```
(define (outer ...)
  (define (inner x ...)
    ...
    (inner ...)
    ...)
  (inner y ...))
```

The nice thing about named `let` is that it puts the definition and the initial call of the local function in the same place.

Cavemen like me who use CL sometimes use macros like `binding`, below, to implement this (note this is not production code: all its error messages are obscure jokes):

```
(defmacro binding (name/bindings &body bindings/decls/forms)
  ;; let / named let
  (typecase name/bindings
    (list
     `(let ,name/bindings ,@bindings/decls/forms))
    (symbol
     (unless (not (null bindings/decls/forms))
       (error "a syntax"))
     (destructuring-bind (bindings . decls/forms) bindings/decls/forms
       (unless (listp bindings)
         (error "another syntax"))
       (unless (listp decls/forms)
         (error "yet another syntax"))
       (multiple-value-bind (args inits)
           (loop for binding in bindings
                 do (unless (and (listp binding)
                                 (= (length binding) 2)
                                 (symbolp (first binding)))
                      (error "a more subtle syntax"))
                 collect (first binding) into args
                 collect (second binding) into inits
                 finally (return (values args inits)))
         `(labels ((,name/bindings ,args
                     ,@decls/forms))
            (,name/bindings ,@inits)))))
    (t
     (error "yet a different syntax"))))
```

Comment: TWIMC: "CL" == "Common Lisp". as we all *know*, Lisp has no syntax! ;) Common Lisp all the more so. All its constructs, starting with `prog`, are just S-expressions! ;)

Comment: @WillNess: Lisp has lots of syntax.  Indeed, since its syntax is user extensible it has an unbounded amount of it.  What it usually *doesn't* have it lots of *lexical* syntax.

Comment: @tfb Thank you, your answer cleared that up nicely. Since I am a scheme hobbyist at best this particular form escaped my notice because I didn’t read all the recursion stuff. I wish it was either explained in the normal let section, or referenced clearly in that section with the name of the section it is actually defined in, or had an alternate name like “letrec-and-execute”

Answer (score 1):

`f` is bound to a procedure that has the body of `let` as a body and `ls` as a parameter.

http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.16

Answer (score 0):

Think of this procedure:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (define (helper lst acc)
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (helper (cdr lst) 
                (+ (car lst) acc))))
  (helper lst 0))

(sum '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 6
```

We can use named `let` instead of defining a local procedure and then use it like this:

```
(define (sum lst-arg)
  (let helper ((lst lst-arg) (acc 0))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (helper (cdr lst) 
                (+ (car lst) acc)))))
```

Those are the exact same code with the exception of some duplicate naming situations. `lst-arg` can have the same name `lst` and it is **never** the same as `lst` inside the `let`.

Named `let` is easy to grasp. `call/cc`usually takes some maturing. I didn't get  `call/cc` before I started creating my own implementations.